# Цикл for , генератор списков, сходство и различия

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Есть две функции, которые, как я раньше думал выполняют одно и то же. Но оказалось, что нет.

```
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def a(su) :                     # функция номер один
    for i in su :
        m = i * i
    return m                    # с z получится  36


def b(su) :                     # функция номер два  
    m = [i * i for i in su]
    return m                    # с z получится [1,4,9,16,25,36]
```

Мне не понятно почему функция **а** перемножает последний элемент списка.По моему замыслу она должна была перемножить все также, как это сделала функция **b**.
Почему это произошло и как это получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции `b` создаётся новый список, каждый элемент которого равен элементу из списка `su`, умноженного на самого себя.

В функции `a` создаётся числовая переменная `m`, которой на каждой итерации присваевается значение текущего элемента списка `su`, умноженного на самого себя.

Функция `a` должна выглядеть так для получения результата аналогичного `b`:

```
def a(su):
    m = []
    for i in su:
        m.append(i * i)
    return m
```

Comment: А почему функция а начинает с последнего элемента списка? А не начинает слева направо по порядку?

Comment: Она проходит по всем элементам. Просто переменная `m` перезаписывается на каждой итерации. Если вы добавите после инструкции `m = i * i` вызов `print(i)`, то сами это увидите.

Answer (score 1):

Для понимания процесса, обратите внимание, что z это список int, следовательно функция а, принимаят и проходя по данному списку, присваивает значение переменной m, которая по правилам типизации (умножение int на int дает int) так же станет int. В то время, как функция b генерирует список значений и присваивает его переменной m.